# IS there an IE add on for html/css vaildation?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, validation

I am looking for a IE9 add on that will clearly show me any html and css validation errors without having to post my source to the w3c validator service.

I know this is possible in firefox (does anyone know what these extensions are called?), but I can't find any for IE.

Comment: for firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/html-validator/

Answer (score 1):

When you say you dont want to post your source to w3c, if you mean you dont want to do it manually, you can use the F12 development tool in IE9, which posts and validates your source with a click.

If you dont want to send your source for some other reason, you can download the offline validator [tidy](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/) from w3c.

[Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) in Firefox is also a great tool.

Answer (score 1):

IE8 includes a "Developer Tools" feature, which does a lot of the same things as Firebug.

You can bring up the Developer Tools window by pressing F12.

I haven't installed the final version of IE9 yet, so I can't double check this still works, but I can't imagine any reason they would have removed it.

If that fails, you could try Firebug Lite. Although Firebug is a Firefox add-on, they do also supply a Lite version which is just a Javascript bookmarklet which can be run on any browser. It doesn't have as many features as the full Firebug, but it is handy for times when you don't have anything else. Get it from here: http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebug Lite (http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite). The original Firebug was an add-on for firefox, but this version runs in all the major browsers and should give you the kind of debugging features you are looking for.